# How to write an inline css to another class from a div?

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I have two div blocks. First div class name is `divone` and the other div class name is `divtwo`. I can write inline style for `divone` but at the same time I want to write inline style at the `divone` block itself for `divtwo`.

Is it possible to write like that?

Comment: You can't write inline style inside one element for another element.

Comment: This is not possible in html and css

Answer (score 0):

The inline css for only the line we were working, that does not refer the another block. If we wants to use either we have to go with the same class name or have a similar inline styles for divone and div two

Answer (score 0):

No It's not Possible.You cannot write style inside one div for another one.
and Writing inline style is not a good practice unless it's that necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. There is only way to make separate class and give it css styles to have same effect in both blocks.